# how to draw an automaton diagram?

Tags: ocaml, graphviz, diagram, dot, finite-automata

I used `graphviz` based on the recommendation given to me by many people but I ran into a problem. I want to write a dot in `ocaml` using the `Format.module` and I have a record with five fields that define an automaton including the transitions which are represented by a list of `int*char*int` and final states which are represented by an `int` list. The first field is the initial state which is one `int`. I also defined a function member that takes a parameter and tests if it is a member of a given list. How can I do so that I can write a full dot that recognizes the initial state and represent it with node `[shape = point]start ; start -> x` and the other transitions with circles and the final states with doublecircles? I tried doing it but I ran into problems When I compile it, it says

> File "automatagraphicstest1.ml", line 44, characters 22-37: Error:
>   This expression has type
>            automate -> Format.formatter -> int * char * int -> unit
>          but an expression was expected of type Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit
>          Type automate is not compatible with type Format.formatter

Comment: Please use a pastebin for your code. A screenshot of your editor is unusable.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QK5qxEhd

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5NSb7qFU this is another try at what i want if you look at it you may understand what i want to do here

Answer (score 0):

To fix your type error, just replace the `fmt_transitions` function by this:

```
let fmt_transitions fmt auto =
  Format.fprintf fmt "@[<v 2>digraph output {@,%a@,@]}@,@."
    (Format.pp_print_list (fmt_transition1 auto)) auto.transitions
```

Your issue is that `pp_print_list` expects something of type `Format.formatter -> 'a -> unit`. Your function `fmt_automaton1` takes the automaton as extra first argument, so we need to partially apply it first, then we can provide the list of transitions.

Comment: i get that but i need to test if an inedge is the int we have in the record as initial state : etat_initial then we have to do node [shape = point]start ; start -> inedge; and also if an outedge is a final state if it belongs to the list etats_finaux then it should be node [shape = doublecircle]outedge;[shape = circle];inedge->outedge[label='by'];

Comment: and shape circle to all the regular transitions but the problem is in fmt

Comment: fmt_transitions* it only takes a list and i don't know what to use to escape the string